# Data is not saving into database in a right manner

Tags: c#

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (CashPaymentGridView.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                CashPaymentandReceivedE cashpament =new CashPaymentandReceivedE();
                List<CashPaymentandReceivedE> cashpaymentList = new List<CashPaymentandReceivedE>();
                foreach ( DataGridViewRow rows in CashPaymentGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (rows.IsNewRow )
                    {
                        break ;
                    }
                    cashpament.VR_NO= Convert.ToInt16(VoucherNoTextBox.Text);
                    cashpament.VR_DATE  = VrDate.Value ;
                    cashpament.ETYPE = "CPV";
                    cashpament.USER_ID = "1";
                    cashpament.PARTY_ID= Convert.ToString (rows.Cells[2].Value)  ;
                    cashpament.DESCRIPTION  = Convert.ToString ( rows.Cells[3].Value);
                    cashpament.INVOICE = Convert.ToString(rows.Cells[4].Value);
                    cashpament.DEBIT  = Convert.ToInt32(rows.Cells[5].Value);
                    cashpament.CREDIT = 0;
                    cashpaymentList.Add(cashpament);

                    cashpament = new CashPaymentandReceivedE();
                    cashpament.VR_NO =Convert.ToInt16(VoucherNoTextBox.Text);
                    cashpament.VR_DATE = VrDate.Value;
                    cashpament.ETYPE = "CPV";
                    cashpament.USER_ID = "1";
                    cashpament.PARTY_ID = NewAccountsDAL.Get_Id_Name ("CASH");
                    cashpament.DESCRIPTION = Convert.ToString(rows.Cells[3].Value);
                    cashpament.INVOICE = Convert.ToString(rows.Cells[4].Value);
                    cashpament.CREDIT = Convert.ToInt32(rows.Cells[5].Value);
                    cashpament.DEBIT = 0;
                    cashpaymentList.Add(cashpament);
                }
                if (CashPaymentandReceivedDAL.Save(cashpaymentList))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SAVE SUCCESSFULLY...............");
                    ResetForm();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show ("Please select atleast one record.....");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message );
        }
    }
```

Stored Procedure for saving data is given as.

```
public static bool Save(List  <CashPaymentandReceivedE> cashreceivedpayment)
    {
        bool blnResult = false;
        SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.Connection);
        //SqlTransaction objSqlTransaction = null;
        try
        {
            objSqlConnection.Open();
            //objSqlTransaction = objSqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
            int R = 0;
            while (R < cashreceivedpayment.Count )
            {

                SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("CASHRECEIVED_Save", objSqlConnection);
                objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //SqlParameter objIdentityParameter = objSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PLED_ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                //objIdentityParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                //objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLED_ID", cashreceivedpayment[R].PLED_ID);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_ID", "1");
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTY_ID", cashreceivedpayment[R].PARTY_ID);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR_NO", cashreceivedpayment[R].VR_NO);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETYPE", cashreceivedpayment[R].ETYPE);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR_DATE", cashreceivedpayment[R].VR_DATE);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION", cashreceivedpayment[R].DESCRIPTION);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEBIT", cashreceivedpayment[R].DEBIT);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREDIT", cashreceivedpayment[R].CREDIT);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER_ID", cashreceivedpayment[R].USER_ID);
                //objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPNAY_ID", cashreceivedpayment[R].COMPANY_ID);
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION2", "DESCRIPTION2");
                objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INVOICE", cashreceivedpayment[R].INVOICE);
                objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                R++;
                blnResult = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //objSqlTransaction.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //objSqlTransaction.Commit();
            objSqlConnection.Close();

        }
        return blnResult;
    }
```

When i save the record, one record should be of Party_id and one should be of cash.
but when i select more than one record just one entry saving to cash. when when i load the record jst one record is loaded.plz help if u understand.....

Comment: In your first loop, move this CashPaymentandReceivedE cashpament =new CashPaymentandReceivedE(); to within the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating *one* `CashPaymentandReceivedE` object, and adding the reference to it on each iteration of the list. You're then also changing all the data *within* that single object on each iteration. Just move this line:

```
CashPaymentandReceivedE cashpament =new CashPaymentandReceivedE();
```

... *inside* your `foreach` statement and the problem should be resolved.

Before you do so though, make sure you understand *why* your code is behaving like this. It's really important to understand that the list doesn't contain *objects* - it contains *references* to objects. In your case, it would contain several references to a single object, until you fix it.

I'd also strongly suggest using a `foreach` in your `Save` method - or if you *really* need the index for some reason, use a `for` loop instead of a `while`.

Comment: Thanks dear. Tell me more about for loop instead foreach. I am new to programming

Comment: @MuhammadShehzad: If you're new to programming, you should *not* be doing database work yet. Take a step back, and learn one thing at a time. Read a good introductory book on C# which will certainly teach you about `for` loops. Stack Overflow is good for addressing individual problems - it's not meant to be a "learn a language from scratch" site though.